# Password authentication in sqlite3 for iphone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, sqlite, uitextfield, uilabel

Hey Guys .. I am new to programming in Objective C .
I checked many tutorials on reading data in sqlite3 , but almost all of them have show the data in UITableView .

I have a page where the user types in the password, the password lets say 1234 is saved in the database ( I have created a table already ) .
I have got the database into the project folder .
I just want a statement like

```
if(databasepassword == correct from the uitextfield )
{
 show next page 
} 
else 
{ 
password is incorrect.text
}
```

I will figure out on how to show the next page and display the password is incorrect.text
I just want a method to cross check with the password saved in the database .
How can I do that ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the sqlite3 API's provided by Apple to read the password from the database. In detail:

1. Add `libsqlite3.dylib` to your list of frameworks
2. Start reading the [SQLite3 documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html), especially the [five-minute guide](http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html).

BTW, do you plan to let the user update this password? If you are just hard-coding a password and deploying it along with the app, then there's not much point in using a SQLite database to store it.

Comment: I will be doing that also later .. But as of now I just wanted the authentication page to work. I don't want to use NSUserDefaults

Comment: I added more detail to the answer. I'd appreciate it if you accepted it (tick the green tick). :-)